# App crashing: Index out of bound at random places

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging, nsarray

My app is crashing at different places but the error is same as below only the index changes sometimes, any idea why is that happening I am attaching my screenshot as well:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x20d4012 0x1e34e7e 0x20760b4 0x152ba 0xdc4067 0xdc42db 0x14fca 0x16aa7 0x239253f 0x23a4014 0x2393fd6 0x23a4014 0x239b8b7 0x2397405 0x2394768 0x207aaf5 0x2079f44 0x2079e1b 0x2ca87e3 0x2ca8668 0xd78ffc 0x2b8d 0x2ab5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

I have tried debugging it to pinpoint exact location or line of code that is causing the crash but with no success. It is just randomly crashing

Thanks[image]

**EDIT 1:**

Alright here's the code:

**Once fetched I am saving them like:**

```
-(void)saveTweetsArray:(NSMutableArray *)array{
    NSString *dbPath = [DatabaseHelper databasePath];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *insertSql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete from %@ where ACCOUNTID='%@'",[DatabaseHelper TweetsTable],self.accountId];
        const char *insertStmt = [insertSql UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertStmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE){
            NSLog(@"old tweets removed");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@" deletion failed");
            NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_errmsg(db)]);
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++){
            NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [array objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *insertSql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into %@ (ID,TWEET_TEXT,USER_NAME,ACCOUNTID) values (?,?,?,?)",[DatabaseHelper TweetsTable]];
            const char *insertStmt = [insertSql UTF8String];
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertStmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [[dictionary valueForKey:@"id"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [[dictionary valueForKey:@"text"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [[dictionary valueForKey:@"userName"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [self.accountId UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
                NSLog(@"data saved");
            else{
                NSLog(@"save failed");
                NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_errmsg(db)]);
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
```

**This is where I am fetching to populate on the tableview while new tweets are fetched:**

```
-(NSMutableArray*)tweetsArray{
    NSMutableArray* tweetsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *dbPath = [DatabaseHelper databasePath];
    if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const NSString *sql_stmt;
        sql_stmt= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select ID,TWEET_TEXT,USER_NAME from %@ where ACCOUNTID='%@' ",[DatabaseHelper TweetsTable],self.accountId];

            const char *sql_stmt1=[sql_stmt UTF8String];
            sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql_stmt1, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
                while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                    // Read the data from the result row
                    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                    [dictionary setValue:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)] forKey:@"id"];
                    [dictionary setValue:((char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1))!=NULL?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)]:@"" forKey:@"text"];
                    [dictionary setValue:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)] forKey:@"userName"];
                    [textsArray addObject:dictionary];
                }
                sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
            }
        }
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return textsArray;
}
```

**This is where I am putting on the tableview after formatting:**

```
        -(void)formatTweetsAndPaintView{
           NSArray *tweets = [dictionary valueForKey:@"twitter"];

        //first save the old tweets to show while new are fetched
           NSMutableArray *tempTweets=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[baseController tweetsArray]];

        //then clear the old tweets then format and fill array
           [[baseController tweetsArray] removeAllObjects];

           if(tweets && tweets.count){
                   for(int i=0;i<[tweets count];i++){
                           NSMutableDictionary *tweetsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                           [tweetsDictionary setValue:[[tweets objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"id_str"]    forKey:@"id"];
                           [tweetsDictionary setValue:[[tweets objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"text"] forKey:@"text"];
                           [tweetsDictionary setValue:[[[tweets objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"user"] valueForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"userName"];

                           [[baseController tweetsArray] addObject:tweetsDictionary];
                   }
             }

//include non duplicate tempTweet to tweetArray
    for(int i=0;i<[tempTweets count];i++){
                if(![[baseController tweetsArray] containsObject:[tempTweets objectAtIndex:i]])
                    [[baseController tweetsArray] addObject:[tempTweets objectAtIndex:i]];
            }

            if([dictionary valueForKey:@"twitter"])
                [baseController setDictionary:[dictionary valueForKey:@"twitter"]];

            [baseController reloadTableViewData];

//finally save the tweets
            [[TweetDB _instance] saveTweetsArray:[baseController tweetsArray]];
        }
```

Comment: post some code please

Comment: Whenever you are fatching value from Array please check array count.Other wise put your code in try catch block.

Comment: Do **not** use try catch blocks in Objective-C except for programming errors that you do not expect to recover from. Not only is this not recommended they do not work correctly across stack frames.

Comment: Use an exception breakpoint.

Comment: Are you manipulating the array while iterating over it? That can cause problems, although I think from memory it'll give u a more specific error to do with that, whereas it seems in your case the values have already changed by the time this is thrown.

Comment: Sorry I have been out. I did try with breakpoints, enabled zombie objects but as you see in the screen shot it shows nothing more than index out of bound at random places. What bobsmells says is something I also suspect, but I don't think I am able to trace it to the point of crash

Comment: Are you able to at least repeatedly trigger one of the scenarios in which this happens? If so could you post some code? I suspect that the most likely candidates are table view controllers because obviously there's lots of collection access going on there.

Comment: I certainly post some code tomorrow. The thing is I am fetching twitter feeds and the first time it runs fine. The next time also it returns full array but out of no where thre is an index  out of bound error.

Comment: sorry, I was away, could you fix it?

Comment: While we wait for your code samples, I did wonder if maybe you're fetching new tweets from a certain twitter feed, then storing it in an array sized according to the number of returned tweets, and then the next time you fetch, there aren't any new tweets and you're trying to store and access in the same "old" array with the previous size. It's hard to speculate exactly without seeing the code but that's one thing that struck me when you said it happens on the second access.

Comment: @bobsmells added the code: Since I can't find any reason why it should crash a pinpoint line of code causing the crash would be really helpful if possible as i think it does changes its value well before throwing the error

Comment: how does your cellForRowAtIndexPath looks like? The problem could be there. The code you posted shouldn't give you any problem though.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to stop your program at the point where it crashes, you need to add an Exception breakpoint.

Go to the Breakpoint Navigator, click on the plus button, and select Add Exception Breakpoint...

[image]

In XCode 5 it will add it straight away, but in previous versions you will need to select : All exceptions

This will stop at where you NSArray is being accessed out of bounds, and then you can debug.

## Edit:

After your program stops, you should be able to see in XCode the line where it crashes. If you don't see the line in XCode, you can in the debugger type:

(lldb) bt

'bt' will print all the steps that the program did to get there, and it will give you the information about what methods were called.

If that doesn't give you the info you need, you can try this way:

Your second option is to repeat the steps before, but instead of selecting Add Exception Breakpoint... you should choose Ad Symbolic Breakpoint...

Once you select it, a pop up window will prompt to enter some values. Enter the following:

[image]

Before crashing it should stop. At that point you can navigate to the Debug Navigator to see what the steps were, and spot the location out:

[image]

As you can see setPrivateProperty is the last time a method was called before stopping.

If the Debug Navigator doesn't give you any information, you can always go to the debugger and type:

(lldb) bt

As before, 'bt' will trace back all the steps to get there in more detail.

All this info should be enough to debug your program. If you need help to interprete the 'bt' output, that's another thread!

Comment: When the breakpoint is hit you may have to "continue" a couple of times to get the message since you are in the exception handler prior to it logging the error information.

Comment: Yeah I added the break point with the options all and objective C but when the crash happens it just logs All Objective C exception and not the place where it is happening. And the next line is index out of bound. This is troubling me for some time now and is just frustrating. :(

Comment: @Zaph If the breakpoint can stop at the exact point where the array emptied or index is out of bounds that can really help, but the thing is it is just printing "All Objective-C Exception" which is not at all helpful or may be I am missing something?

Comment: See my first comment to this answer.

Comment: Did you try Zaph's suggestion?

Comment: Yeah but I didn't use any try catch block in my entire app. And yes I did use continue many times until it said no more debug session available. Coming from java/eclipse background it is a bit difficult. The only thing that looks like an option is to restart afresh from a working copy

Comment: +1 Thanks I was animating the tableView rows but somewhere the arrays were getting cleared and that was causing the crash. I have added the check for empty array and that seem to work now, guess i have to reframe my code

Comment: Surely you could step thru your code a line at a time with the debugger to find out where it's throwing the exception, right?  Even if it's not clear why it's happening you'll know what the culprit line is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the code sample.  I'll have to look thru it in detail when I'm not on my phone, but perhaps when you're creating  tweetsarray by doing    NSMutableArray *tempTweets=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[baseController tweetsArray]] and then doing tweetsArray removeAllobjects, when u then iterate over temptweets it's empty. Try initwitharray:copyitems.